# Answer via video UX

Tags: video, audio, question-answer

How do we design a UX element or workflow on a browser or an app that lets a user answer a fixed question via webcam video or audio instead of text? User can replay what she recorded and re-record if she doesn't like it. User can be 20-60 age range. Some of these users aren't tech savvy but are open to get trained via app itself.

Comment: Please post your designs so we can talk about it

Comment: We don't have designs Nicolas. We are in user research phase of trying to come up with a solution to a business problem. Is there a way we can sync up 1:1?

Answer (score 3):

Understand that you are currently in the user research phase, just like to point out that the way users respond via audio only and video (with or without audio) are very different.
And typically people’s attention span on receiving answers via audio or video are less than 5 seconds because audio and visual cues work based on short term memory usage of users.
So with this in mind if you need to receive audio and visual replies on the application, I’d suggest using a “hold button and record” kind of design, like what the boomerang app/ zoom unmute temporarily function does.
This allows users to be conscious of the time they’re talking to answer and allows viewers to digest short audio-visual replies effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a button that says **Record Answer**

when clicked on Opens up the front camera by default (General Camera UI would Do)

- It should also have the option to trigger back camera
- once you hit the shutter it starts recording
- You Hit the shutter button to stop
- after stopping the recording on the right side of the shutter there will be TICK icon
- and on Left Side there should be a Retake ICON

Clicking on Tick takes you to question page where you see your video attached and ready to submit

clicking on Retake Icon takes user to default State where they can start recording again using the shutter button

Hope this helps Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Let me chew on this. I have reached out to you on LinkedIn.

Comment: I think before taking any action on development, think about the practicality in providing video and audio options to answer as @Eric Chia mentioned to avoid events of users ignored option due to bad design.